# How to make SurfaceView's background transparent without using function setZOrderOnTop(true)?

Tags: java, android, surfaceview

I'm programming a turntable game view by [LuckyPan from github](https://github.com/xuyunqiang/LuckyPan). As you see, it extends a `SurfaceView`.

And here is my problem:

1. I need a background below turntable with picture, it means I need a `SurfaceView` which has a transparent background;
2. `setZOrderOnTop(true)` — I found it to make a transparent background, but it made `SurfaceView` above everything in the APP;
3. Now when I run app in a short phone, the turntable will above the "bottom tab" which is at the bottom of the screen.

So, does anyone has a way can do one of these:
Make `SurfaceView` have a transparent background without using `setZOrderOnTop(true)`.

OR

Set a view above the `SurfaceView` which have already calling `setZOrderOnTop(true)`.

Is this a bug of the `SurfaceView` that always has a not transparent background unless using the `setZOrderOnTop(true)`? If it is, why google hasn't fix it for more than ten years? Or is there something I missed?
Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

> Make SurfaceView have a transparent background without using
>   setZOrderOnTop(true)

```
surface.setBackgroundColor(resources.getColor(R.color.transparent))
```

Forgot: transparent this is a color value in a colors.xml which holds a value "#0000000"

Comment: Thanks for helping.I've tried.This will make the whole surfaceView transparent not only the background.Not what I wanted. 
But still thanks.

Comment: Do you mean that on your SurfaceView drawed something (a pretty green tree, for example), and your backround is just color, maybe blue, and then you want to change this blue color to transparent, but in way to leave the tree as it was before?

Comment: Sorry about my poor English.Can't understand your last sentence well.
I'll draw a circle thing above a picture.
But the circle has a square background.

Comment: Do you want to just draw your SurfaceView with all objects on it, but with transparent background? EDIT: didn't see your comment to end. Just a second...

Comment: I think you are drawing something like picture circle, but it has a white background color, not transparent?

Comment: There is 3 ways to help you

Comment: 1) Use photoshop and make a background of the picture (circle) transparent. 2) Use another picture. 3) Draw a circle with canvas.drawCircle